# Как окружить кавычками текст в Android TextView?

Tags: android-textview, android, textview

Суть в том, что текст, окруженный кавычками, если он не влазит в TextView, урезался не так:

```
"Lorem ipsum...
```

А так:

```
"Lorem ipsu..."
```

То есть урезается текст не с конца, а внутри кавычек.
Думал использовать какой-нибудь Span, но ничего пододящего не нашел, + свой собственный написать не удалось - работал не совсем так, как я ожидал.
Есть вариант делать расчеты самому прямо в канвасе, но мне он не нравится. )

Comment: покажите, как выглядит TextView в XML, или в JAVA коде, где вы вставляете в него текст

Comment: Я бы поступил, наверное, глупо, но быстро. По бокам от нынешнего TextView поставил бы ещё пару TextView, в которых в качестве текста были бы просто кавычки, а в центральном TextView текст бы выводил без кавычек. Но это антиоптимизация! Только скорость разработки выиграется.

Comment: @Lucky_spirit, этого вообще лучше не делать. Какой-то велосипед на квадратных колесах выходит.

Лучше же выводить в textView по-своему, к примеру, нарисовать свою форму отображения/вывода (см. мой ответ ниже).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пришлось прибегнуть к не очень приятному, но надежному способу, а именно - реализовать свой TextView, который расчитывает размер текста на канвасе с учетом кавычек, урезает его, если он не помещается. Для расчета размеров текста использовал `TextPaint.measureText(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

А, если выводить текст в TextView чуть иначе. Так, к примеру.

```
String str = "bla=bla=bla";
textView.setText("\"" + str + "\""); 
// при помощи экранирования можно вывести символ какой-то программно. Или можно применить таблицу символов ASCII. Найти код символа (кавычки) в виде &цифры; и вставить в код.
// Это логика

// А по сути вопроса Вашего нужно просто добавить условие: проверку некоторую

if (str.length() >= КАКОЕ-ТО_ЗНАЧЕНИЕ) {
// выводить так-то (без последней кавычки, к примеру)
} else {
// выводить по-другому или что-то другое сделать
}
```

[@lexx9427](/users/1291/lexx9427), я бы начал думать и писать код в такую сторону. Если данный метод Вам поможет, то рад был помочь!

Comment: Вы видимо не очень поняли мой вопрос. Проблема в том, что КАКОЕ-ТО_ЗНАЧЕНИЕ нельзя расчитать с помощью TextView. Поэтому пришлось делать расчеты на канвасе с помощью TextPaint.measureText

Comment: @lexx9427, да,  мог и неправильно понять Вас.